# Debian increase ulimit for Asterisk

Tags: debian, ulimit, asterisk

I've been facing an issue with Asterisk 13.11.2 on Debian 8 where it's crashing after reaching the limit of open files

```
bridge_channel.c: Can't create pipe! Try increasing max file descriptors with ulimit -n
```

I have managed to increase the limit from 65536 to 150000 using the `/etc/security/limits.conf`

I have added the following:

```
root soft nofile 150000
root hard nofile 150000
* soft nofile 150000
* hard nofile 150000
```

The result of `ulimit -n` is now 150000

When i try check the limit for the Asterisk process `cat /proc/xxx/limits`

I still get the old limit!

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             31945                31945                processes
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       31945                31945                signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

How to solve this?

Comment: If you are using `systemd`, have a look at `man systemd.exec` or [online](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html). In case you are using a SysV script, just add the `ulimit -n <your-number-here>` to the top of your script.

Comment: restart asterisk to make changes of ulimit available (for the new process)

Comment: @RomeoNinov I guess i didn't mention that I did restart the server for the changes to apply. Didn't work

Comment: @TareKhoury is this 64 bit OS? And do you restart it by hand?

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment and change the value of MAXFILES in /usr/sbin/safe_asterisk

ex:
MAXFILES = 150000

save file and restart asterisk

done

Comment: `/usr/sbin/safe_asterisk` does not exactly sound like a file that is supposed to be edited. Note that these changes could be overwritten with the next upgrade of the Asterisk package.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting that your system is using systemd which ignores `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Instead you have to configure these limits in the asterisk service file (`/etc/systemd/system/asterisk.service` or `/lib/systemd/system/asterisk.service`). You probably want to add

```
LimitNOFILE=150000
```

Note that you probably don't want to edit the file that comes with Asterisk since you would run into the risk that your changes would be overwritten with the next Asterisk update. Instead I would recommend to create a file `/etc/systemd/system/asterisk.d/10-file-descriptors.conf` with the line above. Systemd will then automatically augment the official service file with your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

### Set following options in the asterisk.conf

```
[options]
internal_timing = no
maxfiles = 999999
```

[**Complete Solution**](https://serverfault.com/a/1079830/544430)